# <img src ="https://" is not working on server side

Tags: html

I am using html tag to display image on application :

```
<img src ="https://servername/Images/Imagename.JPG" alt ="Logo"/>
```

but image is not coming on page.

I also tried

```
<img src="<%=sHttps%>//servername/Images/Imagename.JPG" alt ="Logo"/>
```

but still is not working.

Comment: Could you give us more details? Which language? Do you get any errors? Is error reporting on?

Comment: @user2342080 ASP scripting..

Comment: Working fine http://jsbin.com/oKeTuDo/1/edit

Comment: have you checked the browser console and network traffic panels for errors (maybe a 404 'not found' error?)

Comment: Doesn't look like your actual image is on the server. - either that or it's corrupt  - reupload and double-check your image location

Comment: i think https secured protocols are not loaded images

Comment: i am using C# code and displaying a html page on server.Apart from all other things are coming only image is not displayed though on local machine its working with http

Comment: I tried with src="//servername/Images/imagename.JPG" still its not working

Answer (score 0):

have you tried. i think this will help you.

```
http://www.xyzabcd.com/images/yourimage.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

[explained here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/httphttps_transitions_and_relative_urls.html) what are the problems occured when the image not loading by using https protocols

And [this link](http://support.volusion.com/article/resolving-insecure-content-secure-pages) also helpful to you for resolving secured content on insecured pages